# openWeatherMap иконки

Tags: android, material-design

Использую openWeatherMap api в приложении и подгружаю оттуда иконки погоды и кеширую, но иконки, откровенно, не лучшего качества.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Существуют ли альтернативные наборы иконок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать библиотеку [Android Iconics](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics) от [Mike Penz](https://github.com/mikepenz) с  набором иконок [Meteocons](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/meteocons/) или [Weather Icons](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/)

Comment: не смог найти информацию для построения url в Weather Icons.как это сделать?

Comment: @UjinUkr не совсем вас понял, о каком `url'e` идёт речь?

Comment: перед загрузкой формирую строку url иконки подставляя в нее данные с строки icon ("icon": "10n"). такая возможность в Weather icons есть?

Comment: @UjinUkr в этой библиотеке всё хранится локально, причём в формате `svg` / `font` что обеспечивает сравнительно маленький добавочный вес для `.apk`

Comment: не совсем то что я хотел, но все ровно спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

[Вот](https://icons8.com/icon/set/weather/all) отличный набор иконок про погоду. В нескольких стилях, в том числе два стиля под Android.

Иконки бесплатные в растре, достаточно указать ссылку на [производителя](https://icons8.ru/) в приложении.

Ну и самое приятное, что всегда можно [дозаказать](https://icons8.ru/request-icon/free/hot) нужную иконку просто расписав подробно, что вам нужно.